# Why does AWS API Gateway websocket send error

Tags: go, websocket, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using serverless framework to set up an AWS API Gateway websocket which calls a lambda function written in Go. Right now the handler only logs a message. I can connect to the websocket, and I can see the message is logged in Cloudwatch when I send a message through the socket, but I always get an error message that looks like

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error",
  "connectionId": "eU3C1cE7CYcCJPw=",
  "requestId": "eU3EQFX0iYcFysQ="
}
```

There are no errors logged for the lambda in Cloudwatch. The AWS API Gateway config looks good to me. I'm at a loss trying to think of what could cause this.

My main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func Handler(request events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest) {
    fmt.Println("default function ran")
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

Probably not super relevant but the serverless.yaml config:

```
functions:
  websocket-default:
    handler: bin/ws
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: $default
```

The payload I'm sending:

```
{
  "action": "whatever",
  "data":  "{whatever}"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only problem in your code, but your handler signature should be one listed in the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-handler-types.html#go-programming-model-handler-types-signatures):

```golang
func ()
func () error
func (TIn) error
func () (TOut, error)
func (context.Context) error
func (context.Context, TIn) error
func (context.Context) (TOut, error)
func (context.Context, TIn) (TOut, error)
```

Comment: My guess was the method signature as well but I can't find an example for a websocket hander in Go. It does run and the `APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest` is populated

Comment: Turned on Cloudwatch logging for API and it's definitely this. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Alright so it took a lot of trial and error but this is the method signature that works

```
type Response events.APIGatewayProxyResponse

func Handler(context context.Context, request events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest) (Response, error)
```

I really wish the documentation for golang was better. Thanks to Clement for pointing me in the right direction.